# Llamar a un archivo con PHP en una carpeta $Variable

Tags: php, html

tengo un pequeño problema espero me podais ayudar un poco con esto, no se mucho de PHP pero hago el intento jeje, vamos mi url es esta

```
http://mipagina.com/creado.php?nombre=llora
```

Intento llamar a la variable de la URL que seria una carpeta ya creada =$nombre para mostrar el archivo datos.txt que esta en esa carpeta

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('$nombre.'/'.datos.txt'); ?>
```

me genera un error, creo que estoy haciendolo mal.. el error es este

```
Division by zero in C:\xammp\htdocs\mipagina\creado.php on line 555

Warning
: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
C:\xammp\htdocs\mipagina\creado.php
on line
555
```

Comment: y que tiene la liena 555 del archivo creado.php?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez en la linea 555 tiene es `<?php echo file_get_contents('$nombre.'/'.datos.txt'); ?>` ahi es donde radica el problema 
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas componiendo el nombre del archivo de forma erronea y te esta interpretando una division. Eso no es lo que quieres escribir.

Estas escribiendo: `file_get_contents('$nombre.'/'.datos.txt');`

Esto esta interpretando una division entre la cadena `llora.` y `.datos.txt`. Por eso te da el error de division entre 0.

Deberias cambiarlo por: `file_get_contents($nombre.'/datos.txt');`

que esto te compone algo como: `llora/datos.txt`

Comment: Hola amigo @Jakala gracias por tu respuesta lo acabo de probar pero me sigue dando error, y el archivo .txt y la carpeta estan creados

Comment: te da el mismo error de division entre cero? o te da otro error? Muestranos el codigo del script, para que veamos si hay algo anterior que solucionar. Por lo que entiendo en tu codigo tendras algo tipo`$nombre = $_GET['nombre']` verdad?

Comment: Este es el error `Undefined variable: nombre in
C:\xammp\htdocs\mipagina\creado.php
on line
555


Warning
: file_get_contents(/datos.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
C:\xammp\htdocs\mipagina\creado.php
on line
555`

Comment: ok. Pues entonces ya sabemos cual es el problema. Te falta de alguna manera cojer el valor de la url (por eso el comentario anterior de utilizar el `$_GET['nombre']`. Si no recojes esa variable no va a componer el archivo correctamente.

Comment: Listo amigo solucionado si era eso.. `$nombre = ($_GET['nombre']);`